# ngx-chips min text length

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I am using a tag input component in an angular form.

https://github.com/Gbuomprisco/ngx-chips

The data comes from a http service (Observable).

I couldn't find in the documentation a way to specify min text length before a rest call should be executed using ngx-chips.

My html fragment is

```
<tag-input name="tagList" [addOnBlur]="true" formControlName="tagList"  theme='bootstrap' [clearOnBlur]="true" [onlyFromAutocomplete]="false" onTextChangeDebounce="100">
   <tag-input-dropdown [autocompleteObservable]="requestTags" >
</tag-input-dropdown>
```

My requestTags function is:

```
public requestTags = (text:string ) =>{
    return this.resourceService.findMatchingTags(text);
};
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at source code seems that tag-input-dropdown has an input property 
minimumTextLength that is the minimum text length in order to display the autocomplete dropdown and not to execute the Observable call.
It could be used as follows:

```
<tag-input name="tagList" [addOnBlur]="true" formControlName="tagList"  theme='bootstrap' [clearOnBlur]="true" [onlyFromAutocomplete]="false" onTextChangeDebounce="100">
   <tag-input-dropdown [autocompleteObservable]="requestTags" [minimumTextLength]="2">
</tag-input-dropdown>
```